Wordpress Plesk cron error / syntax error
I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but i have to start somewhere…
On a client site I get this error message from plesk desk since a couple of days ago:
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'string' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /var/www/vhosts/alexander-schippel.de/httpdocs/pberlin/live/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/includes/class-acf-site-health.php on line 23

It is sent by Cron Daemon via email every hour – and I must admit I have no clue why. Of course I have updated all plugins – and I have googled up and down the internet – but haven't found anythings close to this error message or any suggestion of what could be wrong. I will also ask plesk support, the hosting provider and the people at ACF for help – but I first wanted to see if maybe somebody here has encountered anything similar and could possibly point me in some direction.
Any suggestions or pointers highly appreciated.
